# What does the "reches end of non-void function" error message mean?

Tags: c++, linked-list

keep getting a warring that says:

```
"warning: control reaches end of non-void function"
```

I have a program that has 3 header files and 3 cpp files where functions are being defined. So far I just build the skeleton for said functions and they don't do anything yet. I wondering if this error message will go away once I star defining the functions.

Any guidance would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Non-void functions are ones that are defined to return something. You probably haven't defined a return statement in the skeleton functions yet. Once you add return statements the error will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Void function

```
void foo()
{

}
```

Non-void function

```
int bar()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Non-void function that doesn't return anything

```
int err()
{

}   //"warning: control reaches end of non-void function"
```